# GeoServer + OpenLayers: How can I sum points in a selected polygon in my WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have two layers: one representing admin boundaries (multipolygon), and the other representing population (multipoint). I've made it possible to select a polygon to display. For the displayed polygon, I'd like to display total population, which means summing all the points that belong inside the selected polygon.

Any pointers on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use WPS, the gs:Aggregate process and feed it with a WFS request for that same feature's polygon, chaining it with the collectGeometries process.

Comment: That sounds workable. I've also been going thru `cross layer query`. Split as to which is more appropriate. Do u have any experience working with cross layer queries. What would you advice on their usage for this particular scenario.

Comment: I managed this with a combination filters in the accompanying WFS request. Thanks a lot for the pointer.